# JavaScript Hiding an HTML Form's Submit Button until onsubmit from another input

Tags: javascript, html, input, form-submit, onsubmit

I was able to get the one of the inputs of the form to go from hidden to submit but was not able to get the second attempt. I thus believe I am in the ball park.

```
<?php include("rssUploadFile_code.php"); ?>

<section class="article_centered">
  <h2>RSS File Upload</h2>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="fileToUpload">Upload RSS file:</label>
    <input type='file' name='fileToUpload' id='fileToUpload' /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="openFile" id="openFile" value="Open File" /><br />
    <textarea name="displayFile" rows="6" cols="60" readonly="readonly">
                        <?php echo $fileText; ?></textarea><br />
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $my_rssFile; ?>" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="submitFile" id="submitFile" value="Submit File" />
  </form>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('fileToUpload').onchange = function() {
      document.getElementById('openFile').setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    };
    document.getElementById('openFile').onsubmit = function() {
      document.getElementById('submitFile').setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    };
  </script>
</section>
```

The 'openFile' input works and goes from hidden to submit with fileToUpload onchange. The question is what am I missing on the 'submitFile' input?

I have read similar posts, that is where I took some of my code from. Please let me know if you need further code. There are several files to this RSS coding. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse my English.

The issue is that one form can have only one submit button.

You should not set openFile button to submit instead as a button and use `onclick` event.

Take a look the following code I checked it works fine

```
<section class="article_centered">
  <h2>RSS File Upload</h2>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="fileToUpload">Upload RSS file:</label>
    <input type='file' name='fileToUpload' id='fileToUpload' /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="openFile" id="openFile" value="Open File" /><br />
    <textarea name="displayFile" rows="6" cols="60" readonly="readonly">
                        Text</textarea><br />
    <input type="text" value="Rss File" /><br />

    <input type="hidden" style="" name="submitFile" id="submitFile" value="Submit File" />
  </form>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('fileToUpload').onchange = function() {
      document.getElementById('openFile').setAttribute('type', 'button');
    };
    document.getElementById('openFile').onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById('submitFile').setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    };
  </script>
</section>
```

Sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: I attempted to change the 'onsubmit' to 'onclick'. The result was the 'submitFile' input appeared for less than a second.

Comment: I attempted to change the 'onsubmit' to 'onclick'. The result was the 'submitFile' input appeared for less than a second. I then modified the openFile input to button and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Make the input a `type="button` with `hidden`and then trigger a click.

```
<section class="article_centered">
  <h2>RSS File Upload</h2>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="fileToUpload">Upload RSS file:</label>
    <input type='file' name='fileToUpload' id='fileToUpload' /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="openFile" id="openFile" value="Open File" /><br />
    <textarea name="displayFile" rows="6" cols="60" readonly="readonly">
                        <?php echo $fileText; ?></textarea><br />
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $my_rssFile; ?>" /><br />
    <input type="button" name="submitFile" id="submitFile" value="Submit File" hidden/>
  </form>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('fileToUpload').onchange = function() {
      document.getElementById('openFile').setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    };
    document.getElementById('openFile').onsubmit = function() {
      document.getElementById('submitFile').click();
    };
  </script>
</section>
```

Comment: This appears to be a good way to toggle back and forth with the inputs. I am looking to force somebody through a sequence of events. I thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Since `submit` is really just reserved for `<form>`, you can use `.onclick` instead.

```js
(function() {
      document.getElementById('fileToUpload').onchange = function() {
      document.getElementById('openFile').setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    };
    document.getElementById('openFile').onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById('submitFile').setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    };
})();
```

```html
<input type='file' name='fileToUpload' id='fileToUpload' /><br />

<input type="hidden" name="openFile" id="openFile" value="Open File" /><br />
<textarea name="displayFile" rows="6" cols="60" readonly="readonly">
                        <?php echo $fileText; ?></textarea><br />
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $my_rssFile; ?>" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="submitFile" id="submitFile" value="Submit File" />
```

Comment: Onclick was half my problem, and I thank you for pointing that out.